# how to move to next rows to view in textbox in vb.net 2010 and access database

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi I'm newbie in programming, I'm creating a LAN based entrance examination system which is my school project. The front end I used is visual studio 2010 and the back end is access 2007. Below codes are the combination of my research here in stack overflow. All codes are working when the form loads it populates the combo box for grade level and when I selected a value to the combo box the data was viewed in textboxes but my problem is I don't know how to code the command to move to next rows If I click the button next command and I wasn't sure if my codes below are right, I've been through from many sites but still can't figure out the right code. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

### Below is my code:

```
     Private Sub Examfrm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
     System. EventArgs Handles MyBase.Load

     With conn
     If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
     .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
      Source=C:\Users\Jhoshemaye\Desktop\CAPSTONE    
     FILES\NewCDSC\CDSCDatabase1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            conn.Open()
        End If
    End With

    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT GradeLevel from ExamQuestion GROUPBY GradeLevel", conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Cbolvl.Items.Add(dr("GradeLevel").ToString) 


   Private Sub Cbolvl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,   
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cbolvl.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim query = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM ExamQuestion WHERE GradeLevel = ?"
    Using conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
            Try
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Cbolvl.Text)
                Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    Do While dr.Read
                        subTB.Text = dr.Item("Subcode").ToString
                        questIDTB.Text = dr.Item("QuestionID").ToString
                        questionTB.Text = dr.Item("Question").ToString
                        ansATB.Text = dr.Item("AnsA").ToString
                        ansBTB.Text = dr.Item("AnsB").ToString
                        ansCTB.Text = dr.Item("AnsC").ToString
                        ansDTB.Text = dr.Item("AnsD").ToString

                    Loop
                    If dr.IsClosed = False Then
                        dr.Close()
                    End If

                End Using
            Catch ex As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
    End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: `If I click the button next command` in your post there's nothing there for a button? Can you explain further as of right now nothing makes sense.

Comment: Additionally, you are using `SELECT TOP 1.. ` to fill the textboxes. This means: fetch max one record. You write `to move to next rows` but how should this be possible if you're only fetching one row. Please specificy which `reader` you want to use to read multiple records.

Comment: Hi Sir Zaggler, thank you so much for your time answering my question. my problem regarding the above question were already resolved by my friend. Thanks :D